# Security job visa

Tags: visa

I am presently scouting for a security and safety job in the UK. Is it possible to get a job offer in the UK from a security outfit that is licensed to sponsor before approaching the embassy for visa application.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a job offer from a sponsor before you can get a visa. You cannot get the visa first and then look for a job. The list of sponsors licenced by the government is here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/register-of-licensed-sponsors-workers